# drupal 7 xml sitemap showing nodes that are unpublished

Tags: xml-sitemap

we have xml_sitemap 7.x-2.0-rc1 and drupal 7.23 core and it is putting unpublished nodes in the xml site map. What can we do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solution - turn off the individual node. with the xmlsitemap node module enabled.  at the bottom of the content page when you are editing you can choose Inclusion: Excluded.

Answer (score 1):

Excluding the node manually, isn't really the long term solution. The actual problem resides with the module. There is currently a patch that claims to handle this issue and that's the best place to start.

See this: https://www.drupal.org/node/2266933